# OAuth Handshake Copy Error

Tags: python, oauth, copy

I am trying to build a PoC with the API REST of [Copy](https://developers.copy.com/documentation#authentication/oauth-handshake) but I have a problem when I try to get the ACCESS TOKEN:

Message: oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.copy.com%...

```
@app.route('/get_access_token')
def get_access_token():
    print "Get Access Token"
    oauth_verifier = request.args['oauth_verifier']
    oauth_token = request.args['oauth_token']
    print oauth_token + " & " + oauth_verifier

    # Create your consumer with the proper key/secret.
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    print "Consumer: ", consumer
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)
    url = access_url + "?oauth_verifier=%s&oauth_token=%s" % (oauth_verifier, oauth_token)
    print url
    resp, content = client.request(url, "GET")
    print "Resp: ", resp
    print "Content: ", content

    return content
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my own issue. The problem was the creation of a new consumer (I had one for the first step of the oauth handshake) and not using the oauth.Token provided by the library (I put the oauth_verifier and the oauth_token with a workaround)

The solution:

```
@app.route('/get_access_token')
def get_access_token():
    print "Get Access Token"
    try:
        oauth_verifier = request.args['oauth_verifier']
        oauth_token = request.args['oauth_token']
        print oauth_token + " & " + oauth_verifier

        token = oauth.Token(oauth_token, request_token_secret) # request_token_secret is global
        token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
        client = oauth.Client(consumer, token) #consumer is global

        url = "https://api.copy.com/oauth/access"
        resp, content = client.request(url, "GET")
        print "Resp: ", resp
        print "Content: ", content
        return content

    except Exception as e:
        return e.message()
```

Comment: I AM HAVING the same problem. here is my code        String authorization = String.format("OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"%s\", oauth_token=\"%s\", oauth_signature=\"%s&%s\", oauth_nonce=\"%s\", oauth_timestamp=\"%s\"",
                  Constants.COPY_CONSUMER_KEY,
                  oauthToken, Constants.COPY_SECRET,
                  tokenVerifier,
                  uuid,
                  String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

Comment: what is wrong with my code, i am using same consumer key, if i change it, it gives error invalid key. my signature is mixture of secret and verifier

Comment: Share your formatted code and I will try to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837020/signature-invalid-while-trying-to-retrieve-accestoken-for-copy-api PLEASE have a look at this question

Comment: did u check my question?

Comment: Check you original question