# Signature invalid while trying to retrieve accesToken for copy api

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to load a url with headers and trying to get my accessToken

Here is the code

```
String oauthToken = urls[0];
            String tokenVerifier = urls[1];
            String responseBody = null;

try {
                String url = "https://api.copy.com/oauth/access?oauth_verifier=" + tokenVerifier;
                String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                String authorization = "OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\""+ Constants.COPY_CONSUMER_KEY
                        +"\", oauth_signature=\""+ Constants.COPY_SECRET +"&" + tokenVerifier "\", oauth_nonce=\""+ uniqueID 
                        +"\", oauth_timestamp=\""+String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())+"\" , oauth_token=\""+ oauthToken +"\"";
```

The response gives me error

```
oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.copy.com%2Foauth%2Faccess&oauth_consumer_key%3DCtu6CtdN1PWRo5DstoxgaaIQWZkeeWNg%26oauth_nonce%3D10525625%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1425400347545%26oauth_token%3D6aNkypb7wZoI7dbJiSrtItOTGmpaG0RL%26oauth_verifier%3D496cb46091352c4788603dcfb6e0cfb5%26oauth_version%3D1.0oauth_error_code=2000
```

What is wrong with my signature, same method is working for ios

Comment: what do you use as tokenVerifier ?

Comment: check its ios version , replicate its code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the ouath_token that you have just received when you have to calculate a new Token using that received token and the request_token_secret. This new token is what you need to send as oauth_token parameter in your request.

Check my python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387644/oauth-handshake-copy-error).

Comment: if i change oauthToken to any other value it gives me error invalid token. i am not sure how can i mix both of them to get appropriate token in java :(

Comment: You need something like : OAuthToken makeAccessToken(java.lang.String consumerKey,
                           java.lang.String requestToken,
                           java.lang.String verifier)
                           throws OAuthException

See this library: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/auth/oauth/OAuthProvider.html#getAccessToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29